# jQuery scroll to display a particular DIV on button click

Tags: jquery, html, knockout.js, scroll, jquery-animate

In my html page I have around five buttons.
These are arranged within a single DIV and these buttons are located at the bottom of the page.
When I click on one of those buttons, the page scrolls up.
I want to avoid this behavior. I want to scroll to the same DIV on button click.

Is this possible?

```
<input type="button" value="Update Details" data-bind="onClick: {value: ' Update Details '} />
```

```js
// This is a custom event handler which is raised on button click 
ko.bindingHandlers.onClick = { 
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) { 
        element.onclick = function (event) { 
            event.preventDefault(); 
            // The below function contains business logic 
            UpdateDetails(); 
        }  
    } 
};
```

Comment: Do you mean clicking the button jumps immediately to the top of the page?

Comment: The button is at the bottom of the page. When we click on the button, the page scrolls upwards to its centre. But my requirement here is to focus the same DIV inside which this button is placed.

Comment: Why are you writing your own click binding handler? You should use [Knockout's default click binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html). Also, can you reproduce your problem in a fiddle? You seem to be describing the behaviour of a `<a href="#"></a>` link. Is your button wrapped in a link?

Comment: Can you post the complete DOM structure

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your button is wrapped around div like this

**HTML code:**

`<div class="container">
      <div class="rows"><input type="button" value="Update  Details" data-bind="onClick: {value: ' Update Details '} /></div>
      <div class="rows"><input type="button" value="Update Details" data-bind="onClick: {value: ' Update Details '} /></div>
</div>`

**Knockout code:**

`// This is a custom event handler which is raised on button click 
ko.bindingHandlers.onClick = { 
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) { 
        element.onclick = function (event) { 
            event.preventDefault(); 
            //this will place the target div at top of the page
            $(event.target)[0].scrollIntoView();
            // The below function contains business logic 
            UpdateDetails();
        }
       }
     };`